# How to compare dates in javascript with two different format?

Tags: javascript, date, data-conversion

```
function mainFunc() {
    dueDate = "30/12/2014";
    var firstReminderDate = dueDate;
    var today = new Date();
    var firstDate = convertToDate(firstReminderDate);
    if (today > firstDate) {
        //send reminder to A
    } else {
        // send reminder to B
    }
}

function convertToDate(dateString) {
    var dateData = dateString.split("/");
    var date = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(dateData[0], dateData[1] - 1, dateData[2]));
    return new Date(date);
}
```

I need to compare two dates not the time, and how  to remove the time part and just compare the dates? 
The convertToDate() is returning the "Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 GMT+05:30 1970" everytime?

Comment: use the ISO format:  YYYY-MM-DD,  new Date(dateData[2] + '-' + dateData[1] + '-' + dateData[0])

Comment: The input I am getting as dd/mm/yyyy only

Comment: Date calculations/manipulations? -> Use a library such as [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) :) There are so many pitfalls with dates (formats, leap years, daylight saving time, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code. To get a date from `dd/mm/yyyy`, simply splitting on `/`, reversing the result and joining it on '/' gives you `yyyy/mm/dd`, which is valid input for a new `Date` to compare to some other `Date`. See snippet

```js
var report = document.querySelector('#result');
report.innerHTML += '30/12/2014 => '+ mainFunc('30/12/2014');
report.innerHTML += '<br>01/12/2014 => '+ mainFunc('01/01/2014');

function mainFunc(due) {
    due = due ? convertToDate(due) : new Date;
    return new Date > due 
           ? due +' passed: <b>send reminder to A</b>'
           : due +' not passed: <b>send reminder to B</b>';
}

function convertToDate(dateString) {
    return new Date(dateString.split("/").reverse().join('/'));
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return it in milliseconds format

```
function convertToDate(dateString) {
    var dateData = dateString.split("/");
    return +new Date(new Date().setFullYear(dateData[0], dateData[1] - 1, dateData[2]));
}
```

And also change `var today = new Date();` to `var today = +new Date();`. Now it should work. `+` here converts `Date` object to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to compare two date is to instanciate them with same object, here you must use Date object.

```
function mainFunc(){
    var firstDate = new Date( dueDate = "30/12/2014" );
    today = new Date(); 

    if( today > firstDate ){
     //...
    }
    else{
     //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recomend momentjs lib to parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript.

```
var firstDate = moment("30/12/2014", "DD/MM/YYYY")
var today = moment();

// Format to Unix Timestamp to compare
if(today.format('X') > firstDate.format('X')){

  //send reminder to A
}else{

  // send reminder to B
}
```

Here is the link http://momentjs.com/