# How to compare two different dates which are in two different formats in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare two different time formats in JavaScript.

Day 1: `Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT 2020`

Day 2: Today's date. I am using `today=new Date();` which gives me `Thu Sep 21 2017 11:42:17 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

I want to check if Day 1 is today or in future, basically if Day 1 >= Day 2. 
I am only looking for dates and not datetime.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to put them both into the same format

Comment: Exactly, i was hoping to understand how to put them both in same format.

Comment: First google result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227099/javascript-compare-dates-in-different-formats

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare dates in javascript with two different format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521203/how-to-compare-dates-in-javascript-with-two-different-format)

Comment: My concern is that Day 1 is not capturing time at all. Its just capturing Date and displaying in that format. So, i cant really use parse method or getTime method to compare. If i set Day 1 and Day 2 to same date, they will not have equal values as time is not being captured in Day1.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
let myDate = Date.parse('Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT 2020')
console.log('myDate:', myDate)

let today  = Date.parse(new Date())
console.log('Today:', today)

if (myDate >= today) {
  console.log("True")
} else {
  console.log("False")
}
```

If you use Date.parse() it breaks it down into (I believe) epoch time and makes them comparable. This works with a ton of different date formats.

Comment: Thanks Kelly ! Now my question is why is my code working ! So the logic is working whether i use Date.parse(new Date(myDate)) or just use new Date(myDate). For example, i set my date to today's date. So if the dates are same , i should get true. I am getting it but when i look into log to check the values, they are different ! So how is the JS snippet evaluating them to true ? myDate is 
Thu Sep 21 00:00:00 GMT 2017 and Date.parse(new Date()) is 1506020211000. However, Date.parse(new Date()) for today is 1505952000000. How is the system evaluating these two values to be equal ?!